# Adding a fade in and out transition to background image on hover

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, fade

I have a simple navigation system in a sidebar on a page that you can see [here](http://www.hearingvoicesbrighton.org.uk/).

As you can see when you hover over one of the links in the sidebar the background image changes as I have set a different background URL for hover in the CSS.  I am looking for a simple way of adding a transition effect, so that the hover background image fades in and out.    I have tried a couple of jQuery methods without success. I am wondering if there is a way of adding a fade transition using jQuery or some other method to the background URL image, or whether I have to use a different method to get a transition effect.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: please add the code you have tried with in the question. Use the jquery event of on mouse over and out to acheive your effect

Comment: Are you looking an example like this. http://www.designworks.com.pk/example/background/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say what you're trying to do without some clarification, or some example code, but are you looking for [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/tv5JL/2/)?

```
$("#someElement").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function() {
       $(this).attr("src", "anotherImage.png").fadeIn(1000);
    }); 
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function() {
       $(this).attr("src", "firstImage.png").fadeIn(1000);
    }); 
});
```

In this example, `#someElement` refers to an `img` element. The `src` attribute is changed on hover, with a fade effect.

**Edit** - having re-read your question, I think you want to change the `background-image` CSS property, rather than the `src` of an `img` element. If that's the case, have a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/tv5JL/3/). All that has really changed is replacing the jQuery `attr` function with `css`.

Comment: Thanks,  yes, it is the background-image property I am trying to change.  I don't need any fading in and out of the main background-image as the hover background-image is essentially the same as the main background-image with just an arrow added to the right hand side.  So presumably I can alter the code from the fiddle you linked to so that just the hover background-image is faded in and out?

Comment: Thanks. I can see your code works well for fading one background image out and one back in, which is what my question was about, so I have marked your answer as correct.  I am also looking for a slightly different solution though for just fading in a background image on hover, which would appear behind the foreground image in the DIV, but I will ask a separate question about this.

Answer (score 3):

**Use the following codes:**

```
<div id="someElement" style="background:url('2.jpg');width:100px;height:100px;">
</div>
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#someElement").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function() {
                $(this).css("background", "url('1.jpg')").fadeIn(1000);
            });
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeOut("1000", function() {
                $(this).css("background", "url('2.jpg')").fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.  Because the hover background image is the same as the main background image, with just an arrow added to the right, I don't need any fading in and out of the main background image, just a simple fading in of the hover background image on hover and fading out when the cursor leaves the div

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

This is the HTML element which will have the image in its background:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

**CSS**

We define two CSS classes. The default one for the element which contains `image1.jpg` and a second class which contains `image2.jpg`:

```
.image {
    width: 1000px; /* Image width */
    height: 500px; /* Image height */
    background: url('../images/image1.jpg') no-repeat; /* First image */
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src = "../images/image1.jpg", sizingMethod = 'scale');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
.image.image-2 {
    background: url('../images/image2.jpg') no-repeat;  /* Second image */
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src = "../images/image2.jpg", sizingMethod = 'scale');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

**JavaScript**

The JavaScript uses callbacks/promises to ensure each transition happens in the right sequence:

```
var elem = $('.image'); // Define the element
elem.hover(toggleImage); // When hovering over the element, run the toggleImage function

function toggleImage() {
    // Fade out 0.5 secs, toggle image class, fade in 0.5 secs
    elem.fadeOut(500, function(){
        elem.toggleClass('image-2').promise().done(function(){
            elem.fadeIn(500);
        });
    })
}
```