# How can I change the div background with a transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change my  background with a transition (fade) every 5 sec. How can I realize this?

Comment: Well you start by showing us what you have already tried and we go from there really.

Comment: not possible with css only

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883222/adding-a-fade-in-and-out-transition-to-background-image-on-hover

Comment: check with the [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8527642/2641723) link
Maybe this will helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below code and set the time interval for variable interval

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var img_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var index = 0;
var interval = 5000; //time intervalin milli second
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#fullPage').animate({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    }, 1000);
    $('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url(http://1054.fleeceitout.com/sites/all/themes/jack/images/field.' + img_array[index++ % img_array.length] + '.jpg)');
    $('#fullPage').delay(3000).animate({
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, interval);
}, interval);
```

});

**CSS**

```
body {
background-image: url(field.2.jpg);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
#fullPage {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's nice! But I don't see a transition :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `webkit-animation`.  This will only work in webkit browsers though.  There are simple javascript answers that have been added to the comments but these day it's nicer to do things with CSS, especially if they can gracefully degrade.

http://jsfiddle.net/9G75T/

```
.test {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-animation-name: color2;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes color2 {
      0% {
      }
      25% {
        background: blue;
    }
}
```